# Why is this "First appearance" question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Last I checked, there's nothing wrong with [first-appearance](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-appearance) questions... we have a **tag** for them and everything.

Why is this trivia:

- [What was the first US TV-series in which the main cast were mostly african american?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72094/what-was-the-first-us-tv-series-in-which-the-main-cast-were-mostly-african-ameri)

and all of the others are not?

- [First movie to show All Persons Fictitious Disclaimer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69107/first-movie-to-show-all-persons-fictitious-disclaimer)
- [What was the first "revenge" movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67520/what-was-the-first-revenge-movie)
- [What is the first movie where the voice of the receiving person can be heard in phone conversations?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56098/what-is-the-first-movie-where-the-voice-of-the-receiving-person-can-be-heard-in)

Most of these questions don't even have more content in the question than the closed one... I can understand downvotes but close votes **are not** "super downvotes".

Comment: OK. I get this, but why my question got close vote? Just because I was one of the close-voters for the first question you mentioned?

Comment: Thank you for addressing this :)

Comment: @AJ No clue. Wasn't me. But do you see my point? You asked a very similar question... if not even more trivial... and yet you VTC this question? Why is your question good and this one bad? The first majority black TV show cast is arguably more valuable information than the first use of that legal disclaimer.

Comment: @Catija I do get your point now, but sometimes mistake can happen and I already voted to reopen it.

Comment: This is also an example you might want to include. https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23691/what-was-the-first-movie-that-had-only-female-characters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question was voted off-topic because there is a lack of consistency between the community members in what constitutes a trivia question and what does not.

The reason given was

*"Trivia questions are off-topic; we're not trying to duplicate IMDB."*

Some examples that suggest that this ruling is not consistent with other rulings:

[First appearance of a predominately black cast in a TV show](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41898/first-appearance-of-a-predominately-black-cast-in-a-tv-show?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[What was the first movie that had only female characters?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23691/what-was-the-first-movie-that-had-only-female-characters)

None of these are closed as off-topic. The question in question is actually a duplicate of the question in the top link.

Comment: I notice that the question that you are saying is a duplicate garnered the same answer as well.  Agreed.  The fact that it's a duplicate should have been caught.

Comment: I agree with this answer. The community seems to have closed this question incorrectly. This has since been fixed and it has been reopened and closed as a duplicate of the question mentioned in the answer.